# Why does `rsync` show directories even if it does not make any transfer

Tags: linux, rsync

Sometimes when I use `rsync`, it does not transfer any files (which is expected) but for some reason it outputs some random directories in the shell. For example, take this command:

```
rsync --include="z*" --include="*/" --exclude="*" -az --progress ORIG DEST
```

It correctly downloads all the files that start with the letter `z`. However, if I have absolutely no file starting with the letter `z`, sometimes I see this on my shell:

```
receiving incremental file list
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/arquivos/
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/biblioteca_assinatura_digital/vendor/
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/biblioteca_assinatura_digital/vendor/composer/
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/notas_fiscais_emitidas/2020-06/
ebs1/apache/www/html/controle_pagamentos/notas_fiscais_emitidas/2020-07/
ebs1/apache/www/html/em_criacao/allnetti/imagens/
ebs1/apache/www/html/em_criacao/anlan1/arquivos/
ebs1/apache/www/html/em_criacao/barbantesarara/imagens/
ebs1/apache/www/html/em_criacao/conectesecomputadores/arquivos/
```

Absolutely no file is transfered (which is expected because I have no files starting with the letter `z`), however it shows those directories which contains lots of files but none starts with the letter `z`. Why does this happen?

Comment: This might help: https://superuser.com/a/1580373/340330

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `--prune-empty-dirs` flag (`-m`).

> This  option tells the receiving `rsync` to get rid of empty directories from the file-list, including nested directories that have  no  non-directory  children. This is useful for avoiding the creation of a bunch of useless directories when the sending `rsync` is recursively  scanning  a  hierarchy  of  files  using  `include`/`exclude`/`filter` rules.